# Where to place derived attributes

Tags: database-design, erd

I have an assignment which requires me to design a database.

I have 3 entity types WARD, BED, and BED_ASSIGMENT (which is the "composite" entity type between BED and WARD).

The BED primary key consists of the attributes *bed_id* and *ward_id* (each ward has bed number 1 for example, so I need *ward_id* to properly identify it)

**My question is**:

I have two attributes: *total_bed_ count* and *total_vacant_bed_count*. In which entity type should I place them?

Answer (score 2):

Don't store redundant information. Both `total_bed_count` and `total_vacant_bed_count` can be queried.

`total_bed_count` would be something like `select count(*) from bed`, while `total_vacant_bed_count` could be queried if you know which beds don't have patients assigned to them, maybe something like `select count(*) from bed where patient is null`.